# How to display posts from a specific group in Django?

Tags: django

In my Django setup I have a group called "authors". I want to show their posts on the front page, sorted by date. All of the template examples I can find for groups involve checking the group membership of the currently logged in user, which is not what I want. I simply want to aggregate based on group membership globally, not authenticate or display based on group membership of the user. This seems like it should be a straightforward and common approach, but I'm having a hard time finding a way to do it (and I am also a novice, which does not help I'm sure).

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

group = Group.objects.get(name='authors')
authors = group.user_set.all()
```

Now, you have the list of authors, you can query the list of posts by these users and display it on the home page.